# Retrieving status of IIS in real time

Tags: windows, iis, notifications, push-notification

I want to build a service that will keep polling and will let me know if IIS service on a machine has been reset, and instantly send the status to a client (client could be anything).
I want this to work in a scenario where the target IIS is going to be reset by a lot of people remotely in a network. I came across the command `iisreset /status` which gives me the following output:

```
Status for Windows Process Activation Service ( WAS ) : Running
Status for World Wide Web Publishing Service ( W3SVC ) : Stopped
```

But somehow this approach seems inefficient to me, considering that IIS might get reset very fast and the polling might happen just after IIS resets and no status would get sent to the client.

As an alternative, I am trying to see if there is a log that is maintained for all these activities performed on IIS? Can someone suggest any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The IIS WMI Provider springs to mind: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347459(v=vs.90).aspx

The Windows Management Instrumentation is a very powerful native tool. 
[iis.net](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/scripting) has pratical examples for the WMI providers, including solutions for your problem.